# Defining multiple optional parameters on a route in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have a route

```
.when('/calculator/c_:clientId/t_:type/:assetId',.....)
```

I want make `/t_:type/:assetId` optional

My desired urls could be

```
/calculator/c_100    
/calculator/c_100/t_value1
/calculator/c_100/t_value2/10
```

Is there any way to do this. Using ? can make only one optional and also not the constant part like c_, t_

Answer (score 3):

you just need to add a "?" to you parameter in the route definition

```
.when('/calculator/c_:clientId/t_:type/:assetId?',.....)
```